# combinatoric - eat at least 3 olives

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm struggling to understand how to approach this combinatoric problem:

Suppose you’re eating from a bowl of olives containing 8 castelvetrano olives and 8 kalamata olives. You take olives at random, not seeing which you eat until you put it into your mouth.

(a) How many olives do you have to eat to ensure you’ve eaten at least three of the same kind of olive?

(b) How many olives do you need to eat to ensure you’ve eaten at least three castelvetrano olives

How do I approach this? I initially thought i just find the possibility of picking 3 of kalamata and multiplying that by picking 3 of the total 16 but I'm not sure if that will work.

Answer (score 3):

a) 5: You can eat 2 of each type first

b) 11: You can eat all 8 kalamata's first